# How to get properties of last created book instead of ThisWorkbook?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim fs As Object
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim folder As Object
Set folder = fs.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.path)
Dim file As Object
Dim sKey As String
Dim fileDate As Date

For Each file In folder.Files
If file.DateCreated > fileDate Then
fileDate = file.DateCreated
'sKey = file.Name //  this works but I want next line instead
sKey = file.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Keywords").Value  //  Error is here
End If
Next file
```

Error: object doesn't support this property or method.
By the Way, this works:

```
MsgBox ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Keywords").Value
```

Comment: I just did a quick search [Here]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.builtindocumentproperties(v=vs.80).aspx#Y100 ... It looks like you may need to define the document type, so early binding with specific references to the object type (XL, Word, etc) may be required.

Comment: ThankYou, Scott. It seems that I need a dll.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not opposed to opening the workbook, that is probably the easiest route:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=file.Name, ReadOnly:=True)
skey = wb.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Keywords").Value
wb.Close (False)
```

Alternately, there is a [method which does not require the workbook to be opened](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?t=6827&highlight=DSOFile), but requires a [dll to be downloaded](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=224351).